# What is a good approach on creating a custom robotics gearbox

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, cad, robotics

I would like to put together a custom gearbox of the scale of around 50mmx30mmx30mm to fix a gadget that I am designing.

My question is how should I approach producing this? Should I design components in FreeCAD and have it CNC machined? should I buy the shafts/cogs/bearings and assemble them together? Do I need bearings at all or just shafts and cogs? Is having all components CNC machined cost prohibitive?

I have determined the cog diameters shaft placements and ratios that I need. There are around 6 cogs sitting at various axis, most cogs sit on x-z plane and one sits on the x-y plane. I'm thinking I also need some beveled cogs to mesh the x-z,x-y cogs?

There are 2 inputs to drive the gearbox

1. is a small robotics motor 160rpm max typical runs at 80rpm. The max torque is around 15-20Nm at the driving end, typically only 5Nm needed to operate the system.
2. The second driving input is a knob sitting on a cog which is approx. 100mm diameter.

ratio is 6:1 from motor to final drive and 3:1 from knob to final drive.

BTW my background is in software and electronic engineering but I have started to learn FreeCAD and i'm already building the housing for the gadget in freeCAD.

Thanks

Comment: Unless your name is Musk or Bezos you should choose off the shelf components and put them together.  Gears are expensive to machine.  Save the machining for the case.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to source the parts that fit together specifically. There are bag of mixed parts but I wanted things more specific. I've seen people comment that making a gearbox from mixed parts is messy and a real pain. But then again I don't know anything hence why I want go get a feel for what people usually do in this scenario.

Comment: How can you build the case when it seems you don’t have all the gear ratios and diameters fixed?

Comment: Building your own gearbox is time consuming if you have the machinery and cost prohibitive if you don't, Even moreso if the gearbox itself is not the project unto itself. If your project budget is thousand of dollars, maybe you can spare a thousand dollars to get gearbox case machined from gears off the shelf. If you want the gears also made...well...I've been down this road. My electronics projects are thousands of dollars and a custom gearbox is still way too expensive. Whip up something, anything, Even just a cube, or a box, in eMachineshop and get it auto-quoted. You will see.

Comment: Do consider whether it really needs to be metal. Plastic can be molded or (for prototypes) 3D-printed.

Comment: It did cross my mind for 3D printing, I realised also the torque values I posted were incorrect, Im dealing with less than 1Nm from the motor. Ill look into 3D printing perhaps thats the path I will take.